# Unable to login Nexus 7 using Virtual Router created from desktop

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, nexus-7

Hi I've recently bought a Nexus 7 and since I didn't had a Wi-Fi or a 3G sim card right now, I just tried to connect the device using my laptop's internet connection. For this, I just created a Virtual Router and connected my Nexus's Wi-Fi with the router. It is perfectly connected however when I tried to login into my google account, it says:

> can't establish a reliable connection to the server nexus 7

Comment: I've found a solutin [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2110225), however I don't wanna try this as I've read somewhere that rooting the device voids the warranty.

Comment: That warranty part is true -- unless you live inside the EU.

Comment: As mentioned in several posts, I've tried factory-reset, youtube trick and login from some different account but no luck at all. Is there any other work around ? I've even tried a different Wi-Fi Network, but still the same issue persists.